# Java RMI, Can I send a serialized object without putting the class file @ the webserver?

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I'm experimenting with RMI lately and found out that I seem to be unable to send a serialized object if the class file isn't also stored at the webserver. Does this mean that all my serializable classes need to be put in the webservers classpath?

Doesn't really seem like the best design to me IMHO.

Comment: Yes they need to exist in both the server and client classpath.  As far as it not being the best design, keep in mind that it is as old as Java EE itself and was pretty cutting edge for the time.  In the days of SOAP and web services though it is something of a relic.

Comment: Thanks, now you mentioned that it is that old I can see why some things are not as smooth as I like them to be.

Comment: AFAIK, The method implementations of an object are not in the serialized version of the object. You need the class definition for that. I suppose you could define your own classloader and send across the class definitions in advance for objects you haven't yet encountered. Of course, you'd better trust your client to only send code you feel comfortable executing, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No.* All these answers are wrong.

The classes *don't* need to exist at both sides if you use the RMI codebase feature. You can set up a Web server to host the JAR files and set -Djava.rmi.server.codebase= to define where those classes are available as a list of URLs of those JAR files. You set that at either the server or the client or both depending on who is going to be sending classes that the other side doesn't have. Then RMI annotates those classes with those URLs so the target knows where to get them, and downloads them as needed.

Comment: this will put the classes on both sides

Comment: @MauricePerry It will load them dynamically from the codebase side to the target side. It isn't the same as a static 'put'.

Comment: @EJP well the OP explicitly said He didn't want that

Comment: @MauricePerry He explicitly said that he didn't want to 'put the serialized classes into the webserver's CLASSPATH'. The RMI codebase feature *loads* them automatically, dynamically, on demand, *into the server VM.* It doesn't have anything to do with the CLASSPATH. Ergo it isn't what he 'explicitly said he didn't want'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the classes must exist on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the class file must exist on the webserver as well, as RMI was intended (way back when) to send an instance of a class across the wire.  If you are simply looking to send data to a web server without any encapsulating class business behavior, then there are much newer and simpler ways (JSON, XML, SOAP, etc) to simply send data.